# How to play sound in custom keyboard

Tags: java, android, audio

I've recently made my own keyboard that is always shown to the user.
I've also found how to play sounds while pressing a key but if I press one and then inmediatly another, only plays the first sound.
Is there any way for making the sound to be played each time I press a key even if there's 0,1 millisecond between them?
Here is my code:

```
 final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sn_tecla);
 final MediaPlayer mpspc = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sn_spc);
    texto1.setTypeface(fuente);


    //This is for each key.
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
            texto1.setText(texto1.getText() + "1");

        }
    });
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use soundpool
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

```
SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
/** soundId for Later handling of sound pool **/
int soundId = sp.load(MainActivity.this, R.raw.windows_8_notify, 1); // in 2nd param u    have to pass your desire ringtone

sp.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this allows you to play two different sound files at once? Even if it's just that you can use `sp.play` twice in a row and it works as the asker wants, it's best to explicitly point that out.

Comment: it says "cannot find symbol context".
Sorry im a newbie with this :c, do I have to declare context variable or write something instead?:c

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by declaring a mediaPlayer object for each of your buttons(a slight overhead, but it works). 
Also, instead of an **onClickListener**, use an **onTouchListener**.

For example: If you have 2 buttons and each have to make the same sound, Your code will go like this:

```
final MediaPlayer[] mediaPlayers = new MediaPlayer[2];

    for(int i =0;i<2;i++){

        //if both buttons ought to have the same sound
        mediaPlayers[i] = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.beep);
        mediaPlayers[i].setLooping(true);

    }

    button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            //when the user presses the button
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                mediaPlayers[0].start();
                texto1.setText(texto1.getText() + "1");
                }

            //when the user releases the button
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                mediaPlayers[0].pause();


            }

            return false;
        }
    });
    button2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
               {
                mediaPlayers[1].start();
                texto1.setText(texto1.getText() + "1");
               }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                mediaPlayers[1].pause();

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: It works but now each time I press a key, it writes the character twice :c

Comment: I think you might have written your setText code for **Action_Up as well as Action_Down**, while you just require it for Action_Down. 
Make the changes i've made in the `ACTION_DOWN` answer above.

Comment: As I cant paste my code directly here due to characters limit, I made an screenshot and uploaded it here: http://i62.tinypic.com/4kaauc.jpg

I doesnt work properly yet :s now I have problems with the sound, which sounds different each time I press a key (sometimes plays the right sound and sometimes plays it wrong :s)

Comment: The code in your picture seems correct. Please provide the complete code

Comment: As my code is very large, here you have it at my dropbox acc https://goo.gl/5cHtla

Comment: btn2 has an onClickListener as well as an onTouchListener. Remove the onClickListener

Comment: okay and what do I do with the sound playing issues and the double character typing each time I press btn1?